# Missing right parenthesis error in decode line with listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, decode

In select statement i used this decode statement and error is appearing as missing right parenthesis in this line

```
DECODE(KZNM_ISWHYWHY,'N',LISTAGG(WWDT_ANSWER,chr(10) || chr(10)) within 
group(order by WWDT_ANSWER),KZNM_ANALYSIS)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the parentheses in the small code segment you have posted. The error will probably be in the surrounding SQL statement somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with this line of code and as you can see in below example it executes correctly (note that you have to group by kznm_iswhywhy as well as by kznm_analysis);

```
create table kznm(kznm_iswhywhy varchar2(10), wwdt_answer varchar2(10),     kznm_analysis varchar2(10));
 /
 select 
     DECODE(kznm_iswhywhy, 
     'N',listagg(wwdt_answer
     ,chr(10)        || chr(10))  within GROUP(ORDER BY    wwdt_answer),kznm_analysis) 
     from kznm
    group by kznm_iswhywhy, kznm_analysis
/
```

Comment: okay thats right, i tried it's working in oracle 12c but not in oracle 10g

Comment: listagg was introduces only in 11g r2, so now it is clear why you get an error